# Convert HList to Map with shapless

Tags: shapeless

i start work with shapeless, and as proof of concept, i defined function for convert Hlist to Map, but something went wrong, can you help me please?

```
object bar extends Poly1 {
   implicit def caseTuple[T, U](implicit st: Case.Aux[T, Map[String, Any]], su: Case.Aux[U, Map[String, Any]]) =
  at[(T, U)](t => {
    Map(s"${t._1}" -> t._2)
  })
}

object foo extends Poly2 {
implicit def default[T](implicit st: bar.Case.Aux[T, Map[String, Any]]) =
  at[Map[String, Any], T] { (acc, t) =>
    acc ++ bar(t)
  }
}

val h = ("k1", 1) :: ("k2", "foo") :: HNil
println(h.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Any])(foo))
```

But i got error: `could not find implicit value for parameter folder: shapeless.ops.hlist.LeftFolder[shapeless.::[(String, Int),shapeless.::[(String, String),shapeless.HNil]],scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any],Main.foo.type]
[error]   println(h.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Any])(foo))`

Answer (score 1):

1. As you don't care about the value type, you don't need dedicated polymorphic function for the value type.
2. If you're just relying on `.toString`, you don't need a `Poly1` so that the above example can be rewritten like this:

```scala
object foo1 extends Poly2 {
  implicit def default[K, V] =
    at[Map[String, Any], (K, V)] { case (acc, (k, v)) =>
      acc + (k.toString -> v)
    }
}

val h = ("k1", 1) :: ("k2", "foo") :: (true, "TRUE") :: HNil
println(h.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Any])(foo1))
// Map(k1 -> 1, k2 -> foo, true -> TRUE)
```

3. If you have multiple types in the key position, you need to convert them to string. It can be `Poly1` or any typeclass such as `scalaz.Show` or `cats.Show` which provide `A => String`.

```scala
object bar2 extends Poly1 {
  implicit val stringCase = at[String](identity)
  implicit val symbolCase = at[Symbol](_.name)
  implicit def integralCase[A: Integral] = at[A](_.toString)
  implicit def fractionalCase[A: Fractional] = at[A](_ formatted "%.2f")
}

object foo2 extends Poly2 {
  implicit def default[K, V](implicit bk: bar2.Case.Aux[K, String]) =
    at[Map[String, Any], (K, V)] { case (acc, (k, v)) =>
      acc + (bk(k) -> v)
    }
}

val h2 = ("k1", 1) :: ("k2", "foo") :: ('k3, true) :: (12.3456, 'frac) :: HNil
println(h2.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Any])(foo2))
// Map(k1 -> 1, k2 -> foo, k3 -> true, 12.35 -> 'frac)
```

You can do the same to have another key type instead of `Any`.